# Вопросы вместо текста, подключение к бд которой нет

Tags: php, mysql

В общем это даже не проблема, просто любопытство не дает покоя.
Есть код PHP, который пытается установить соединение с **несуществующей** бд.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$dbTestConnection = new mysqli('localhost', 'admin', '', 'dasd');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
?>
```

В браузере выводит:

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): ��������� ��
>   �����������, �.�. ������ ������� ������ ������ �� ���������. in
>   E:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\r2\exmple_mysql.php on line 4 Не удалось
>   подключиться: ����������� �� �����������, �.�. �������� ���������
>   ������ ������ �� �����������.

если удалить из header utf-8 вот так:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=');
```

то браузер выводит

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002):
>   пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ пїЅпїЅ пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ,
>   пїЅ.пїЅ. пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ
>   пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ пїЅпїЅ пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ. in E:\Program
>   Files\xampp\htdocs\r2\exmple_mysql.php on line 4 РќРµ СѓРґР°Р»РѕСЃСЊ
>   РїРѕРґРєР»СЋС‡РёС‚СЊСЃСЏ: Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный
>   компьютер отверг запрос на подключение.

То есть что не отображалось до этого стало отображаться, но перестало отображаться то что было.

Вопрос: как сделать так чтобы все корректно отображалось?
Что я пытался:

- В папке с php файлом создал .htacces и прописал AddDefaultCharset
  Windows-1251 и еще utf-8 пытался - не помогло.
- В php.ini стоит default_charset="UTF-8"
- В \apache\conf\httpd.conf прописал строчку AddDefaultCharset utf-8
- Файл php сохранен в utf-8

Пытался еще настройки mySQL менять всякие, и через php установить кодировку mysql - ничего не помогло, хотя по логике и не должно, ведь mysql выключена.

Comment: вы же заметили что только текст самой ошибки Mysql у вас выводится не корректно, да?

Comment: Да, заметил. Так я и хочу чтобы этот текст отображался. Если например включить mysql и написать неправильного пользователя или типа того то все отображается нормально

Comment: ну я к тому, что настройки апача там или  кодировка файла и т.п. здесь не при делах, и ковыряться надо в настройках подключения к БД. Т.е. возможно опции mysql в php.ini, если таковые есть, либо настройки сервера и т.п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем отвечая на вопрос как сделать чтобы все нормально отображалось нашел ответ: поменял в windows язык, регион, язык интерфейса на Английский/США. Теперь все отображается нормально. Не знаю что именно из этого помогло, видимо до этого сообщение об ошибке отправлялось на русском языке, теперь на английском. 
Решение конечно так себе)

Answer (score 1):

Дело совсем не в настройках php или apache.
Поменяйте язык сообщений в my.ini

```
lc-messages=en_US
```

Так будет хотя бы по-английски.

См. также

1. Параметр [lc-message](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lc_messages) (по-английски)
2. Параметр [lc-message-dir](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lc_messages_dir) (по-английски)
3. [Где искать my.ini в Windows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html#option-files-windows) (по-английски)

Comment: Спасибо за инфу конечно, но я так понял эти настройки влияют на сообщения только когда сервер mysql запущен, а он у меня выключен. Проблема возникает когда он выключен, пока он включен все ошибки отображаются нормально.